# Automatically share a single folder from EC2 instance with clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, filesystems, share

I have data computed from a daily crawler on my AWS EC2 instance that I need to share with clients and other users outside of AWS. The data gets updated every day and the clients need access to this information whenever it changes. Currently I have been automatically uploading the new data to drop box but this is less than ideal because it can only be accessed through browser and not directly from disk and it is available to anyone with the link. I have messed around with google drive and have looked into getting a shared AWS S3 bucket but these solutions have not been working out as well. What is the best way to put this data (and only this data folder) from my EC2 instance onto a shared folder that my clients can view? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: How many files? How big are the files? How many "clients" do you have? How can your clients currently authenticate to prove their identity? How do your clients use the data -- do they download it all every day? Do they refer back to historical data, or are they only interested in the "latest" version? Does every client get access to the same data, or is it different for every client? Please Edit your question to provide more information like this (don't put it in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with S3?

I would go with something like this.

1. create S3 bucket that will hold the data that you want to share (don't make it public)
2. create cronjob at that instance and use s3 api to periodically send data to the above s3 bucket
3. create signed urls for and distribute them to your clients

This way, only your clients can access the data and they can access both via browser or using CURL or GET command from command line.